# In the Apache ActiveMQ library, what happened to `xbean` between the 5.7.0 and 5.8.0 versions?

Tags: activemq-classic

My project depends on Apache's [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) library, and I am trying to update that dependency. One particular package within ActiveMQ my project depends on, `org.apache.activemq.xbean`, seems to have disappeared during the update from version 5.7.0 to 5.8.0.

In the update to version 5.8.0, the [release notes](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release) explain that `activemq-core-5.7.0.jar` has been replaced with `activemq-client-5.8.0.jar` and `activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar`.

> 1. New modules may effect your maven pom dependencies activemq-core has
>      been replaced with activemq-client and activemq-broker. The various
>      message stores have their own activemq-xx-store module. The uber
>      module activemq-all remains.

I downloaded the consecutive versions 5.7.0 and 5.8.0 from ActiveMQ's [past releases page](https://activemq.apache.org/download-archives), and confirmed that the `xbean` package is included in the 5.7.0 version's `activemq-core-5.7.0.jar` but in not the 5.8.0 version in either `activemq-client-5.8.0.jar` or `activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar`. Swapping `activemq-core-5.7.0.jar` for `activemq-client-5.8.0.jar` and `activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar` therefore causes my package to break, as it uses the `org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean` class.

1. What happened to the `org.apache.activemq.xbean` package during this
   update?
2. Is it still included in ActiveMQ library somewhere?
3. Can I still access it, there or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean is in activemq-spring-5.8.0 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-spring/5.8.0